# Meteor + polymer without blaze

Tags: javascript, meteor, polymer, spacebars

I'm trying to use meteor + polymer without blaze templating. 
I make this behavior:

```
    MeteorBehavior = {
    properties: {
        isReady: {
            type: Boolean,
            value: false,
            notify: true
        },
        currentUser: {
            type: Object,
            value: null,
            notify: true
        }
    },
    ready: function () {
        var self = this;
        self.subscriptions.forEach(function(itm){
            itm = $.type(itm) == 'array' ? itm : [itm];
            itm[itm.length] = function () {
                self.isReady = true;
            };
            Meteor.subscribe.apply(null, itm);
        });
        Meteor.startup(function () {
            Tracker.autorun(function(){
                self.currentUser = Meteor.user();
            });
            Tracker.autorun(self.autorun.bind(self));
        });
    },
    subscriptions: [],
    autorun: function() { }
};
```

And i use it:

```
  (function () {
    Polymer({
        is: 'posts-list',
        posts: [],
        behaviors: [MeteorBehavior],
        autorun: function(){
            this.posts = Posts.find().fetch();
        },
        subscriptions: ['posts']
    });
})();
```

Is it good solution? And how i can animate data changing without blaze uihooks?

Comment: So it works like you wish it does?

Comment: @Kyll yes it works. My question is "Is it good solution? And how i can animate data changing without blaze uihooks?"

Comment: Okay, just wanted to make sure because your first question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it seems to be opinion-based ("I like that solution, ..."). I suggest to [edit] it out of your post.